# Angular.js custom directive not showing up multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I've got a Angular.js directive I'm writing to reduce some boilerplate with Twitter Bootstrap. So far I've created a `form-input` element and it displays as expected. However, if I place many of these directives in the same parent element, only the first one actually gets added and shows up.

Can anyone shed some light on why?

My markup:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <form-input type="text" target="name1" label="Name1" placeholder="Doug" ng-model="name1"/>
        <form-input type="text" target="name2" label="Name2" placeholder="Frank" ng-model="name2"/>
    </form>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);


app.controller('FormInputController', ['$scope', '$attrs', function($scope, $attrs){
    console.log("Controller");
}]);

app.directive('formInput', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'FormInputController',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        require: ['^ngModel'],
        template: '<div class="form-group">'
                + '<label for="{{id}}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{label}}</label>'
                + '<div class="col-sm-10">'
                  + '<input type="{{type}}" class="form-control" id="{{id}}" placeholder="{{placeholder}}">'
                + '</div>'
              + '</div>',
        scope: {
            id: '@',
            label: '@',
            placeholder: '@',
            type: "@"
        },

        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
            console.log(arguments);
        }
    };
});
```

As stated above, only the "Doug" input shows up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular element directives not displaying when using self-closing tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103183/angular-element-directives-not-displaying-when-using-self-closing-tags)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use "self closing" tags for your directives. If you change your [markup](http://plnkr.co/edit/LdHeBl2HhJnAMiPskz1E?p=preview) as follows it should work:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <form-input type="text" target="name1" label="Name1" placeholder="Doug" ng-model="name1"></form-input>
    <form-input type="text" target="name2" label="Name2" placeholder="Frank" ng-model="name2"></form-input>
</form>
```

Basically, the way that HTML parses `<form-input />` is as an open tag without a close tag, so your first directive is started, but never finished, which is why the first one appears to work, but the second one not.

See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5) and [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1953) for more details.

Comment: `<directive-name />` markup gave me problems too. Any advantage to using it?

Comment: Still a helpful answer in 2016 after going through answers talking to isolated scope for my directive which I already had. Thanks.