# AngularJS - html under my directive is not showing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

[Please see relevant jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hwujvbf/1/)

Within this file I have two spans 'test1' and 'test2'. The span 'test2' is showing but the span underneath my custom directive 'test1' is not showing or being called into the page at all. Why?

```
<div ng-app="HelloApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <search-bar/> <!-- The Search Bar Directive -->
        <span>test1</span>
    </div>
    <span>test2</span>
</div>
```

Angular Code

```
var app = angular.module('HelloApp', [])

app.directive('searchBar', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        template: '<input type="text" ng-model="searchData" placeholder="Enter a search" id="searchbarid" />',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('keyup', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.search(elem);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

    var items = ["ask","always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo", "blackberry",    "tweet","force9", "westerners", "sport"];

    $scope.search = function(element) {
        $("#searchbarid").autocomplete({
                 source: items
     });

    };
});
```

Comment: `<search-bar></search-bar>` seems to work for me

Comment: @timeiscoffee Nice catch..I've added the detail version of answer...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular element directives not displaying when using self-closing tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103183/angular-element-directives-not-displaying-when-using-self-closing-tags)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you are doing `<search-bar/>` that means you are considering the directive element tag as a self-closing tag. Custom html elements are not self-closing by nature, so you should close the element of your directive like `<search-bar> </search-bar>`

Currently your `<span>test1</span>` is disappearing because you have not closed you directive element, so the browser does close that element by itself where its parent element gets closed like here `div` with `ng-controller` is parent

**Before Rendering**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <search-bar/> <!-- The Search Bar Directive -->
    <span>test1</span>
</div>
```

**After Rendering**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <search-bar></search-bar>
</div>
```

There after the directive start its working on the element & replace the directive element with the input element.

Here are [**list of self closing html tags**](http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html)

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7hwujvbf/3/)

Comment: @JamesWiseman Glad to here someone likes it. Thanks for edit & appreciation :)

Answer (score 1):

you cant use  in angular ... its just not valid. You must close directive, with close tag

```
<div ng-app="HelloApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <search-bar> </search-bar><!-- The Search Bar Directive -->
        <span>test1</span>
    </div>
    <span>test2</span>
</div>
```