# Making a directive that can group radio options

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a input radio element as angular directive with 3 possible options; none, single and double.

I also want the user to be able to select only from none to single, from single to double and from double to none.

In this case my element will looks like this :

```
<tribox id="{{id}}" name="{{name}}" type="{{type}}" />
```

Also sometimes I need to be able to group bunch of them together in which case I would add group attribute into it like so :

```
<tribox id="{{id}}" name="{{name}}" type="{{type}}" group="cheese" />
```

Tribox gets generated from the following template:

```
<div class="tribox">

    <input id="{{id}}-none" type="radio" name="{{(group)?group:name}}" ng-model="val" value="0" />
    <label for="{{id}}-none" ng-show="val == 2" class="none">{{name}}</label>

    <input id="{{id}}-single" type="radio" name="{{(group)?group:name}}" ng-model="val" value="1" />
    <label for="{{id}}-single" ng-show="!val || val==0" class="single">{{name}}</label>

    <input id="{{id}}-double" type="radio" name="{{(group)?group:name}}" ng-model="val" value="2" />
    <label for="{{id}}-double" ng-show="val == 1" class="double">{{name}}</label>

</div>
```

**Question**

The problem I am having is that when I choose to group bunch of elements together my program is not really grouping it. is this because of the tribox element that I'm using? or is it because of the ng-show attributes that I have used! what's the clean logical workaround !

[Click here for example](http://jsfiddle.net/princem3/4yujuvfm/10)

Comment: can't use self closing tags for custom elements like `<tribox></tribox>`. Otherwise not clear what the issue is. Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: @charlietfl is correct [you can't have self closing custom element](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31148026/2435473)

Comment: @charlietfl you see the directive/element is working fine; the issue is when I group them.

Comment: well we can't see what the problem is....create a demo

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/princem3/4yujuvfm/10/

Comment: What do you mean by grouping them together? If they are in the same group is there some expected change in functionality?

Comment: if you look into the example the user should be able to choose one cheese and one sauce but whatever topping