# Which is the best way to use React child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

In particular, I'm curious about the way to pass information along. In another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48991212/react-component-closing-tag), I had child components and the methods of passing certain props explained to me, as well as the dangers of `<MyComponent children={...} />`, and I'm curious which would be better: storing and working with the tabs as a mapped array of objects as in the example, or following the 
`<TabList> <Tab /><Tab /> </TabList>` style. Is `<MyComponent children={...} />`  the same as `<TabList tabs={this.state.tabs} />`? I assume so, but apparently children as a prop is special case?

```js
const tabs = [
                {
          id: 0,
          label: "Archery",
          content: "Lorem Ipsum 1"
        },
                {
          id: 1,
          label: "Baseball",
          content: "Lorem Ipsum 2"
        }
      ];

function TabContent(props) {
  return (
    <div className="tabContent">
    {props.content}
    </div>
  );
}

class Tab extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onClick(el) {
    this.props.handleClick(el.target)
  }

  render() {
    let active = (this.props.id === this.props.activeTab) ? "active" : ""
    return (
      <li id={this.props.id} onClick={this.onClick} className={active}>
        {this.props.label}
      </li>
    );
  }
}

class TabList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    $(this.refs.tabList).animate({scrollLeft: this.props.scrollPosition}, 400)
  }

  render() {
    let tabList = this.props.tabs.map((tab) => {
        return (
        <Tab 
          key={tab.id}
          id={tab.id}
          activeTab={this.props.activeTab}
          label={tab.label}
          handleClick={this.props.handleClick}
        />
      );
    });
    return (
        <ul className="tabList" ref="tabList">
        {tabList}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

class TabScroller extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="tabScroller">
        <div className="NavList">
          <TabNav handleClick={this.handleNavClick} />
          <TabList 
            tabs={this.state.tabs} 
            activeTab={this.state.activeTab}
            scrollPosition={this.state.scrollPosition} 
            handleClick={this.handleTabClick}
          />
        </div>
        <TabContent content={this.state.tabs[this.state.activeTab].content} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

ReactDOM.render(
  <TabScroller />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, anything within `<TabList></TabList>` will be passed to the TabList component as `props.children` which includes all functions and props that might be added to child Components. This, among other reasons, is why it's more often best to pass the children as child Components rather than props and avoid having to unnecessarily duplicate props.

I have no single resource to officially confirm this, just experience gained through playing around in React.js, so if anyone can comment or DM me a link, I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `<TabList> <Tab /><Tab /> </TabList>` is just a syntax sugar that JSX has brought. Internally, it's the same as `<TabList children={[<Tab />, <Tab />]} />`.