# What is the difference between these two View components?

Tags: react-native, react-360

I am looking at react-360 and react-native code and found the following examples concerning the `View` component.

```
class ViewColoredBoxesWithText extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', height: 100, padding: 20}}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', flex: 0.3}} />
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red', flex: 0.5}} />
        <Text>Hello World!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Why are the children View components self closing whereas the parent View component is not.

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/hEc4k5pN17GZq/giphy.gif. It will not be that maybe it's because one is a father and the others are not?

Comment: In order to nest components you open and close the parent one separately. On the other hand, if it doesn't have a child, it can (must) be closed with a self tag after its props.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the parent `<View>` you cannot use self closing because it has to  wrap children components between the opening and closing tags.

In case of child `<View>` you are not wrapping any children within the tag, so you are using open with the choice to use self-closing **or** separate closing tag. This is the **JSX** feature same applies for all the tags such as `<div>`, `<p>` or other custom elements.

you can get to know about it in more depth [JSX in Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

Answer (score 0):

Because the parent View component has children components while the children View components do not. See this related Stack Overflow question: ([React component closing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48991212/react-component-closing-tag))