# react nesting 3 components opening and closing tag where when the element inside the tag isnt rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found a similar question here: [React component closing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48991212/react-component-closing-tag)
but i am still confuse...

why when I do this it doesnt work? innertherinner doesnt get rendered.

```
function Outer(props) {
  return (
    <Inner>
      <InnerTheInner />
    </Inner>
  )
}

function Inner(props) {
  return (
    <>

    </>
  )
}

function InnerTheInner() {
  return (
    <>
      innertheinner
    </>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Outer user='nishi' avatar='avatar photo' />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

isnt it equivalent to this:

```
<Outer>
  <Inner>
    <InnerTheInner>
        InnerTheInner
      </InnerTheInner>
  </Inner>
</Outer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
function Inner(props) {
  return <>{props.children}</>;
}
```

else it would just render always

```
  return (
    <>

    </>
  )
```

Checkout https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Answer (score 0):

In fact you're rendering an empty Fragment using `Inner` component - without any child nodes. React components do not render its children inside unless you tell them to do so explicitly:

```js
function Inner(props) {
  return (
    <>
      {props.children}
    </>
  )
}
```

That way, every component that is passed inside the `<Inner>` will be rendered (as it's a part of the `children` prop).

Also you can simplify it, as there's no need to use Fragment at all, just return `props.children` and you're good to go.

```js
function Inner(props) {
  return props.children
}
```

Comment: commenting on @meteor answer too. if I have to declare props.children, what i the point of opening and closing a componnent and have a child inside? i could just set <InnerTheInner/> on Outer itself.

Comment: Not quite should I've understood you correctly, but probably you're missing the point of things like `<></>`. They are called Fragments and allow you to return multiple elements inside without using ```key``` props. Read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html). In your example there's no sense of using them at all, honestly.