# How to see nested react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I see sample react component usecase,for example following is listed.
But I have questions.`<App />` means some react component and it has some html element.
But regarding `<Theme></Theme>` , it is also react component. but why this is different writing form from `<App />`? what is the difference between them?

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Theme>
        <App />
      </Theme>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

I am totally novice of React,and search them but I still have unclear about it.
If someone has materials relating that.
Will you please let me know

thanks

Comment: not sure if this waht u were looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48991212/react-component-closing-tag

Comment: React is structured like HTML, you can put components inside of other components for readability and reusability.

Answer (score 1):

If you define component that have `children` in props, you should use it as pair tag, and whatever is inside of it, its passed to `props.children`.
In your example imagine that `Theme` can look somehow like this:

```
const Theme = ({children}) =>{
return <div style={{backgroundColor: red, color: blue}}>
 {children} //this is where <App /> is rendered in your case
</div>
}
```